# How to check if a file has completed uploading into S3 Bucket using Boto in Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, flask

I'm trying to upload an image into S3 bucket using boto. After the image has successfully uploaded, I want to perform a certain operation using the file URL of the image in the S3 bucket. The problem is that sometimes the image doesn't upload fast enough and I end up with a server error when I want to perform the operation dependent on the file URL of the Image.

This is my source code. I'm using python flask.

```
def search_test(consumer_id):

consumer = session.query(Consumer).filter_by(consumer_id=consumer_id).one()
products = session.query(Product).all()
product_dictionary = {'Products': [p.serialize for p in products]}

if request.method == 'POST':
    p_product_image_url = request.files['product_upload_url']
    s3 = boto.connect_s3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    bucket = s3.get_bucket(AWS_BUCKET_NAME)
    k = Key(bucket)
    if p_product_image_url and allowed_file(p_product_image_url.filename):

        # Read the contents of the file
        file_content = p_product_image_url.read()

        # Use Boto to upload the file to S3
        k.set_metadata('Content-Type', mimetypes.guess_type(p_product_image_url.filename))
        k.key = secure_filename(p_product_image_url.filename)
        k.set_contents_from_string(file_content)
        print ('consumer search upload successful')

    new_upload = Uploads(picture_upload_url=k.key.replace(' ', '+'), consumer=consumer)
    session.add(new_upload)
    session.commit()

    new_result = jsonify(Result=perform_actual_search(amazon_s3_base_url + k.key.replace(' ', '+'),

                                                      product_dictionary))

    return new_result
else:
    return render_template('upload_demo.html', consumer_id=consumer_id)
```

The jsonify method needs a valid image url to perform the operation. It works sometimes, sometimes it doesn't. The reason I suspect being due to the issue that the image would not have uploaded yet by the time it executes that line of code.

The perform_actual_search method is as follows:

```
def get_image_search_results(image_url):
global description
url = ('http://style.vsapi01.com/api-search/by-url/?apikey=%s&url=%s' % (just_visual_api_key, image_url))
h = httplib2.Http()
response, content = h.request(url,
                              'GET')  # alternatively write content=h.request((url,'GET')[1]) ///Numbr 2 in our array
result = json.loads(content)

result_dictionary = []

for i in range(0, 10):
    if result:
        try:
            if result['errorMessage']:
                result_dictionary = []
        except:
            pass

            if result['images'][i]:
                images = result['images'][i]
                jv_img_url = images['imageUrl']
                title = images['title']
                try:
                    if images['description']:
                        description = images['description']
                    else:
                        description = "no description"
                except:
                    pass

                # print("\njv_img_url: %s,\ntitle: %s,\ndescription: %s\n\n"% (
                # jv_img_url, title, description))

                image_info = {
                    'image_url': jv_img_url,
                    'title': title,
                    'description': description,
                }
                result_dictionary.append(image_info)

if result_dictionary != []:
    # for i in range(len(result_dictionary)):
    #     print (result_dictionary[i])
    #     print("\n\n")
    return result_dictionary
else:
    return []


def performSearch(jv_input_dictionary, imagernce_products_dict):
print jv_input_dictionary
print imagernce_products_dict

global common_desc_ratio
global isReady
image_search_results = []
if jv_input_dictionary != []:
    for i in range(len(jv_input_dictionary)):
        print jv_input_dictionary[i]
        for key in jv_input_dictionary[i]:
            if key == 'description':
                input_description = jv_input_dictionary[i][key]
                s1w = re.findall('\w+', input_description.lower())
                s1count = Counter(s1w)
                print input_description
                for j in imagernce_products_dict:
                    if j == 'Products':
                        for q in range(len(imagernce_products_dict['Products'])):
                            for key2 in imagernce_products_dict['Products'][q]:
                                if key2 == 'description':
                                    search_description = imagernce_products_dict['Products'][q]['description']
                                    print search_description
                                    s2w = re.findall('\w+', search_description.lower())
                                    s2count = Counter(s2w)
                                    # Commonality magic
                                    common_desc_ratio = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, s1w, s2w).ratio()
                                    print('Common ratio is: %.2f' % common_desc_ratio)

                            if common_desc_ratio > 0.09:
                                image_search_results.append(imagernce_products_dict['Products'][q])

if image_search_results:

    print image_search_results
    return image_search_results
else:
    return {'404': 'No retailers registered with us currently own this product.'}


def perform_actual_search(image_url, imagernce_product_dictionary):
return performSearch(get_image_search_results(image_url), imagernce_product_dictionary)
```

Any help solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would configure S3 to generate notifications on events such as s3:ObjectCreated:*

Notifications can be posted to an SNS topic, a SQS queue or directly trigger a lambda function.

More details about S3 notifications : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html

You should rewrite your code to separate the upload part and the image processing part.  The later can be implemented as a Lambda function in Python.
Working in an Asynchronous way is key here, writing blocking code is usually not scalable.

Answer (score 1):

you can compare bytes written to s3 with file size. lets say you use following method to write to s3:

`bytes_written = key.set_contents_from_file(file_binary, rewind=True)` 
in your case it's `set_contents_from_string`

then I would compare, `bytes_written` with `p_product_image_url.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)`

if they match. whole file has been uploaded to s3.